# data binding ListView Inside Listview

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a class with ObservableCollection which one if is field is another ObservableCollection.

and I want to show the data in 1 row for the first ObservableCollection and using a plus sign or something else user can open the listview and see the other row which is the second ObseravableCollection.

however I am getting an error that could not take data from memory

will appreciate help with code example

attaching my code below

XAML

```
 <ListView x:Name="dgEditEvent" ItemsSource="{Binding OMH1}"  >
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding a}" Width="50"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding b}" Width="50"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding c}" Width="50"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding d}" Width="50"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Moshav1 }" Width="50"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

C#

```
public class Hartza : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _a;

    public string a
    {
       get
        {
            return _a;
        }

        set
        {
            _a = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("a");
        }
    }

    private string _b;


    public string b
    {
        get
        {
            return _b;
        }

        set
        {
            _b = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("b");
        }
    }

    private string _c;

    public string c
    {
        get
        {
            return _c;
        }

        set
        {
            _c = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("c");
        }
    }
    private string _d;

    public string d
    {
        get
        {
            return _d;
        }

        set
        {
            _d = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("d");
        }
    }


    public ObservableCollection<Moshav> Moshav1 { get; set; }

    public Hartza()
    {
        _a = "";
        _b = "";
        _c = "";
        _d = "";
        Moshav1 = new ObservableCollection<Moshav>();

    }







    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public class Moshav
    {
        private string _e;

        public string e
        {
            get
            {
                return _e;
            }

            set
            {
                _e = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("e");
            }
        }

        private string _f;

        public string f
        {
            get
            {
                return _f;

            }

            set
            {
                    _f = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("f");
            }
        }


        private string _g;
        public string g
        {
            get
            {
                return _g;
            }

            set
            {
                _g = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("g");
            }
        }



        public Moshav()
        {
            _e = "";
            _f = "";
            _g = "";
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }


    }
}

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _selectedEvent = new Modules.ShelegEventDetails();
        LM = new List<Modules.ShelegEventDetails>();
        LMA = new List<Modules.AppEvent>();
        _selectedAppEvent = new Modules.AppEvent();

        //dgEditEvent.Items.Add(a);







        Modules.Hartza.Moshav m = new Modules.Hartza.Moshav();

        m.e = "5";
        m.f = "5";
        m.g = "5";


        Modules.Hartza H = new Modules.Hartza();

        H.a = "1";
        H.b = "2";
        H.c = "3";
        H.d = "4";

        H.Moshav1.Add(m);


        OMH = new ObservableCollection<Hartza>();
        OMH.Add(H);


        //dgEditEvent.ItemsSource = OMH;


        dgEditEvent.ItemsSource = OMH1;
        dgEditEvent.DataContext = OMH1;




    }
```

Comment: is it necessary to be in a `ListView`? the `DataGrid` displays the data in the same format you want and has the `RowDetailsTemplate` which would in fact be a detail of what you have in each row, and it appears when you click on the row, it would be exactly what you are looking for, but in a `DataGrid`

Comment: Why are you using a ListBox.ItemTemplate inside a ListView ? I don't think it will work that way. And secondly is your OHM and OHM1 the same object because I don't see you adding anything in OHM1.

Comment: can be data grid or list boxbut how I show this data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a nested `ListView`:

```
<ListView x:Name="dgEditEvent" ItemsSource="{Binding OMH1}"  >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding a}" Width="50"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding b}" Width="50" Grid.Row="1"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding c}" Width="50" Grid.Row="2"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding d}" Width="50" Grid.Row="3"></TextBlock>

                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Moshav1}" Grid.Row="4">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding e}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding f}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding g}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

You may also put it in an `Expander`:

```
<Expander Header="Expand/Collapse..." Grid.Row="4">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Moshav1}" Grid.Row="4">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding e}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding f}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding g}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Expander>
```